# TypeScript - Error calling jQuery getJSON() function

Tags: typescript, tsd

I am using TypeScript 1.7.5 and the latest jQuery type definition. The following call to $.getJSON() fails with "error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target"

```
let url: string = api + '/orgs/' + orgname + '/repos?per_page=100';
$.getJSON(url, function(repos: Repo[]) {
    ...
});
```

Repo is defined as:

```
export interface Repo {
    name: string;
    stargazers_count: number;
    forks_count: number;
}
```

The type definition for getJSON() is:

```
getJSON(url: string, success?: (data: any, textStatus: string, jqXHR: JQueryXHR) => any): JQueryXHR;
```

What am I missing?

**Update**

I found that the error is really coming from chaining a call to `error()`, which is perfectly legal in regular jQuery. If I remove this call to `error()` the error goes away. Any idea how I could handle the error from `getJSON()` in TypeScript?

```
interface Repo {
    name: string;
    stargazers_count: number;
    forks_count: number;
}
var url = "/echo/json/";

$.getJSON(url, (data: any, textStatus: string, jqXHR: JQueryXHR) => {
    var repos: Repo[] = data;
    //...
    alert(JSON.stringify(repos));
})
.error(function() {
    callback([]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can help:

```
$.getJSON(url, (data: any, textStatus: string, jqXHR: JQueryXHR) => {
    var repos: Repo[] = data;
    //...
});
```

Please check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2bnhden/).

#### Update 1.

You should use "fail" to process errors:

```
interface Repo {
    name: string;
    stargazers_count: number;
    forks_count: number;
}
var url = "/echo/json/";

$.getJSON(url, (data: any, textStatus: string, jqXHR: JQueryXHR) => {
    var repos: Repo[] = data;
    //...
    alert(JSON.stringify(repos));
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("error!");
    //callback([]);
});
```

Comment: That's much better than what I had, but it is still giving the same error :-(

Comment: I've created jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/q2bnhden/) it compiles and works like a charm for me.

Comment: Thanks, @TSV. Still no success. I am using `tsc` through an npm script. Must be something wrong with my setup. Still checking...

Comment: Found it! The error is really coming from chaining a call to `error()`. Please see my update. Can you think of a solution?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for all your help, @TSV.